# I keep getting an error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Good Morning, I keep getting an error in my XML file that says
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: ScrollView can host only one direct child
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child.

How do i go about to start fixing this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.exampleapplication.foodorder.functionalities.account.AccountViewModel"
            />
    </data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/receivecontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".functionalities.orderlist.firsttime.ReceiveCodeFragment">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/receivecontainer">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/receivebackbtn"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blackarrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.695" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        style="@style/Title24"
        android:layout_width="373dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/receiverestauranttitle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/receiverestaurantfooter"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startterminal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/coldGrey9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.050"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView3"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:textColor="@color/coldGrey8"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/whiteColor"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.268"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:strokeColor="@color/coldGrey3"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp"
        tools:cardElevation="0dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/restaurantEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="Enter email here"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="@{viewModel.profile.locationEmail}"
            android:textColor="@color/coldGrey8"
            android:textColorHint="@color/coldGrey5"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView3" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendHtmlcode"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/coldGrey4"
        android:letterSpacing="0.03"
        android:text="@string/sendHtml"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

What does it mean by directly only one child and it only occurs when i try to add a scrollview into the XML file into the application

Comment: [`ScollView`/`NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) , can have only one child view, Wrap all your views inside `NestedScrollView` inside a view group - `LinearLayout` , `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Place a constraint layout inside ScrollView and then add all the views inside Scrollview inside the new constraint layout..

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much tells you everything you need to know. The ScrollView can only host a single child view in order for it to work properly. You need to wrap everything inside the scroll view in a container. Seeing that you use constraints for positioning the elements, you'll want to wrap them inside a ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` can only have one direct child. It can't have multiple child Like you used.

Wrap all your views in a `Linear Layout` (or any other ie: Constraint, Relative) like this (Assuming all your views are vertically oriented):

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/receivecontainer">

   <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/receivebackbtn"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blackarrow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.695" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        style="@style/Title24"
        android:layout_width="373dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/receiverestauranttitle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/receiverestaurantfooter"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startterminal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textColor="@color/coldGrey9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.050"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView3"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:textColor="@color/coldGrey8"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/whiteColor"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.268"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
        app:strokeColor="@color/coldGrey3"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp"
        tools:cardElevation="0dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/restaurantEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:hint="Enter email here"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="@{viewModel.profile.locationEmail}"
            android:textColor="@color/coldGrey8"
            android:textColorHint="@color/coldGrey5"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView3" />

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendHtmlcode"
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/coldGrey4"
        android:letterSpacing="0.03"
        android:text="@string/sendHtml"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
    
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the views by LinearLayout/RelativeLayout/ConstraintLayout(or any other viewgroup as per view relations) and put that container viewgroup inside NestedScrollView like,

```
<NestedScrollView>
 
  <LinearLayout>

     //Other Views will go here...

  </LinearLayout>

</NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all the child views present in NestedScrollView to either ConstraintLayout or LinearLayout or RelativeLayout (or any other viewgroup) and put that newly created parent layout inside NestedScrollView. It will solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.exampleapplication.foodorder.functionalities.account.AccountViewModel"
            />
    </data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/receivecontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".functionalities.orderlist.firsttime.ReceiveCodeFragment">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/receivecontainer">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/receivebackbtn"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/blackarrow"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.695" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                style="@style/Title24"
                android:layout_width="373dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="@string/receiverestauranttitle"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.076" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="280dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text="@string/receiverestaurantfooter"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/startterminal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
                android:text="Email"
                android:textColor="@color/coldGrey9"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.050"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView3"
                android:layout_width="310dp"
                android:layout_height="52dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:textColor="@color/coldGrey8"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/whiteColor"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.268"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView7"
                app:strokeColor="@color/coldGrey3"
                app:strokeWidth="2dp"
                tools:cardElevation="0dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/restaurantEmail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:hint="Enter email here"
                    android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                    android:text="@{viewModel.profile.locationEmail}"
                    android:textColor="@color/coldGrey8"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/coldGrey5"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView3" />

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendHtmlcode"
                android:layout_width="330dp"
                android:layout_height="60sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/coldGrey4"
                android:letterSpacing="0.03"
                android:text="@string/sendHtml"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```